# multiplying a numpy lhs Unit eigenvector times a numpy matrix

Tags: python, numpy, linear-algebra, eigenvector

I have a matrix `T`:

```
[ 0.2  0.4  0.4]
[ 0.8  0.2  0. ]
[ 0.8  0.   0.2]
```

I want to  multiply it by a lhs row vector (s1,s2,s3) and set the product expression equal to the elements of the corresponding rhs column vector so it would be

```
vl * T = s( ..., ..., ...)
```

This will be equivalent to solving three linear equations from which you can solve for the eigenvector elements up to a scaling factor. Setting the sum of the elements equal to 1 then gives you the unit eigenvector.

For example, to get started, multiplying the lhs row vector times the first column of the matrix and setting the product equal to s1 gives you the equation 0.2 x s1 + 0.8 x s2 + 0.8 x s3 = s1.

The other two equations are obtained by multiplying the lhs row vector times the second and third columns of the matrix, and setting the products equal to s2 and s3, respectively.
Solving these three equations will give you the relative values among s1, s2, and s3. Setting the sum of these equal to 1 will then give you the unit eigenvector elements.

I want to do this using python, here is my attempt:

```
    >>> import numpy as np
    >>> from scipy.linalg import eig
    >>> np.set_printoptions(precision=4)
    >>> T = np.mat("0.2 0.4 0.4;0.8 0.2 0.0;0.8 0.0 0.2")
    >>> np.set_printoptions(precision=4)
    >>> w, vl, vr = eig(T, left=True)
    >>> vlUnit = vl[:,1]/sum(vl[:,1])
    >>> s = vlUnit 
    >>> s
    array([  7.3543e+15,  -3.6772e+15,  -3.6772e+15])
```

So I know both `vl` and `VlUnit` are type `numpy.array` and `T` is matrix

I also cant read the results of `s`.

I converted and its `7354300000000000, -3677200000000000, 3677200000000000` which don't look right to me. What am I doing wrong??

Thanks,

Chris

Comment: v1Unit is not a unit-vector (if that was what you needed). Unit vectors you get by dividing with the length (the sqroot of the sum of the squared elements). Also, if s is just the unit-vector why not call it that directly?

Comment: deinonychusaur, thanks! I didn't know ...

Comment: deinonychusaur any advice on how to do this?

Comment: s=vl[:,1]/sqrt(sum(vl[:,1]**2)) like this? Lemming gave it to me!

Comment: Do you have a reference I can use for that and read up?

Comment: matrix([[ -4.4126e+15,   2.2063e+15,   2.2063e+15]]) Does not look right either ...

Comment: Did you really use my code below? It should be much smaller values then.

Answer (score 1):

This should give you the v1 unit vector:

```
v1Unit = np.linalg.norm(v1[:, 1])
```

Comment: Thanks deinonychusaur, 1) How is v1Unit = np.linalg.norm(v1[:, 1]) different from v1Unit [:,1]/sqrt(sum(vl[:,1]**2))? 2) am I correctly multiplying my vl * T in python to solve the problem?

Comment: should be the same thing just looks neater to use np.linalg.norm

Comment: Thanks mate! I am learning allot I need to know if I am doing the multiplication correctly. What are your thoughts?

Comment: v1Unit = np.linalg.norm(v1[:, 1]) gives me a value of 1.